# What should I do if I find a software is horribly designed?

Tags: software-development

Say, I am assigned to work on a software project in a university. The software is horribly designed, and the source code doesn't even have 10% comments.

They said that they have been working on this software for 1 year. I see this software would take at most a month for me to write from scratch.

Right now, I am trying to understand the code. While I am reading the code, I have been bombarded each second by my subconscious self with the temptation to re-write the entire software from scratch.

What should I do?

Comment: Hey there. Is this part of some University project of some course or similar of the career you are taking, or is this part of your job as a professional?

Comment: @DarkCygnus, this is a job.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So, I guess that you "inherited" the project, as you are reading the code that was already made by someone else. Who is this someone else? Are they still part of the project?

Comment: @DarkCygnus, *Who is this someone else?* --- random students. *Are they still part of the project?* --- the project leader is a Ph.D. student. She has been around from the beginning. Others are gone.

Comment: Ask the project leader

Comment: This sounds more like a Software engineering question than a workpace question.

Comment: "I see this software would take at most a month for me to write from scratch." I can not count how many times I heard that, or actually said it myself. It's probably not so easy... Crappy software is usually not caused only by bad dev, but many things like unclear or changing requirements, dependancies, ...  When faced with such things I would usually give the rewrite a try, maybe partly on my own time even. After 1 week you already get a better idea whether this is indeed a 1 month work or you were optimistic...

Comment: This is completely normal in software.  It is as exciting as saying "I arrived at a software job and saw computers everywhere!"  It is a 1000x duplicate, new programmer is shocked, shocked at low quality engineering.

Comment: Anytime a person says they can write something from scratch in a month, I apply the old rule of software development management - "take the time, bump up a time period and double it". So, something that the programmer says will take a month is far more likely to take 2 years to write, fully debug, and get stable with all the options needed.

Comment: Do you have experience implementing a project of this size and complexity from scratch? Did it take the amount of time you originally estimated it would? Do you have a sound rational basis to be confident in your belief that you could reimplement it better in such a short time?

Comment: There's bad software and there's bad bad software, but I would argue about "source code doesn't even have 10% comments". There's software out there that doesn't require a bunch of comment if you have good documentation of the functional (!) process and the code follows these processes. Nothing worse than mindlessly adding documentation, such as "Gets or sets the date of publication" for a property or field called "PublicationDate" just because someone said "we should have at least 80% comments" (80% of what anyway). I'd rather do without.

Comment: @Helena It's not really software-specific. It could just as easily have been "I just joined a company in their accounting department and I found that the way they track payables is terrible. I am tempted to overhaul their payables process. It would only take me a month. What should I do?"  The "new kid comes in and finds everything not to their liking and considers themself a savior" is a tale as old as time.

Comment: @AndyLester maybe you are right and i have just reading it as a software engineering question, as I would have given a software engineering answer.

Comment: A rule in software development: If a developer estimates anything higher than one or two days for a task, the developer has no idea how long it will actually take, and needs to break it down into smaller tasks before even getting in the right ballpark.

Comment: @davidr looks like the software won't even take a month. I am almost done. I think, I can finish it before 25th February. If that is so, it will take 22 days from scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What should I do?

You should express your concerns in a professional and polite way to the project leader.

Seems that you know who the leader is (this Ph.D. student), so you should take your concerns, to them, explain why those things are potentially wrong and if possible the general idea you have to solve those problems.

I must say again that this should be done politely and professionally. Don't go to them and say *"The project sucks, it's all wrong"*. Just stick to the facts, say what's wrong and what could be improved, and avoid making remarks based on feelings/emotions.

In general terms there are two possible outcomes of this:

1. The project leader takes your advice, asks you for a work plan, and you all start refactoring and reworking on the project.
2. The project leader says *"Yes, I am aware, but we must continue and complete it with what we got now"*.

You should be prepared for those possible outcomes (and the possibilities in between) and decide what you are willing to do on either of them (that is, decide if you are still up to the task if the second option results).

Comment: Spot on for the considered diplomatic approach, and for the fact it talks about refactoring and not the "complete rewrite"

Comment: Actually, your suggestion worked. I didn't tell them that I will redesign the software from scratch. I proposed modification one after another. So, I have been able to feed them an entire elephant very slowly.

Comment: @user366312 that's great to hear, hope that everything goes well with the project now and that you are able to bring it into shape :)

Answer (score 19):

You can propose the idea to your manager but, in my experience, management is generally *not* supportive of full rewrites.

How long would a rewrite take you? What if the ETA for a complete rewrite would be two years and you leave after one year? And what if you're being paid $100k / year. If you leave before finishing your rewrite the owner / manager just lost $100k with barely anything to show for it.

How many other developers do you work with right now? Let's say it's two others and that they're comfortable enough with it. Replacing code that two people are okay with and that you, singularly, are not, is probably not going to fly.

How old is the code base? How many other developers have come and gone that made changes to that code base? If you're using some sort of VCS you could figure this out. But if no developer over the past ten years has had issues with the code and you're the first one that is then the manager is likely going to assume that it's not the code that's the problem but you. And even if the past devs did complain about the code, if he didn't let them do a rewrite why would you assume that your request would be any different?

Also, quoting https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/ ,

> It’s important to remember that when you start from scratch there is **absolutely no reason** to believe that you are going to do a better job than you did the first time. First of all, you probably don’t even have the same programming team that worked on version one, so you don’t actually have “more experience”. You’re just going to make most of the old mistakes again, and introduce some new problems that weren’t in the original version.

...and...

> [When you rewrite code you] are throwing away your market leadership. You are giving a gift of two or three years to your competitors, and believe me, that is a long time in software years.

If you want to maximize the likelihood that your request will get the desired response I'd prepare responses to each of the questions I've posed.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. And if you don't know what to do, you write unit tests if they're missing. You focus those unit tests on the parts they want you to work on, or on the parts you need to understand. In the meantime, you work on your resume and you send it out to other employers. Now at least, you know a couple more questions to ask during an interview before you accept a job offer.

Answer (score 6):

You have a **job** at this company, and I imagine very strongly your job isn't to re-write the app and waste time starting from scratch.

As someone who's been on the management side of this debate, it makes me entirely question whether I made the right hire - I tell someone what I want them to do, potentially in intricate detail, and they **fail to keep their eye on the ball and do it.**

If your task is to add a widget to a web page, do that. Spend time reviewing code for potential beneficial tweaks **later.**

100% **do not waste company time on a frivolous task, even writing up why your frivolous task should be done.** It will not be appreciated. That's not to say, don't spend your own time outside of company hours doing it, but you should really consider how this will be received.

Managers are likely aware of the spaghetti status of their code, and are focused on actual deliverables and features. If you can add comments and documentation as you add to the existing code, hey that's great. Proposing you ditch whatever they already have and rebuild it, however, shows an extreme mismatch on vision and experience and will likely just irritate your manager.

Not just because they'll have to say no (and really managers dislike conflict, even though they have to be able to handle it well), but also because they then need to formulate a reason. Your manager might spend a good 30 minutes trying to explain why this needs to be this way.... and at that point you haven't just wasted **your own time wondering why not rebuild everything,** but also that of your manager, when you could have just done what they asked you to do.

Sorry for the harsh tone in this post but i've seen it a lot and it is extremely frustrating as a manager to have employees who can't hear "Can you please build x" and then they do everything but that

^ Now, if there's a technical issue with the way the existing code is written (do NOT go looking for one just to justify your whims, if they catch you on that they'll be disgusted), it is very much appropriate to explain "I have tried building this widget this way, but the module/library we've used here doesn't support doing it that way" - this makes sense. But very definitely, don't get lost in the idea that code must be written "the right way" or not at all. In almost any company, there is an extreme demand / supply inequality as far as things development resources need to do vs how many people are available and how much time is available to do it, so proposing anything here that might waste time just so that the code will be written better... I really can't articulate how irritating that may be to others.

If you write up your own code in addition to theirs, just set an example and write it well, document it well, etc. But absolutely, do not waste time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119553/discussion-on-answer-by-schizoid04-what-should-i-do-if-i-find-a-software-is-horr).

Comment: *"Can you please build x"* - a large problem of managements is they don't (want to) understand that perhaps x can't simply be built without further action. Perhaps x takes long to do without further preparation and the whole thing will crash at the latest when y should be built too? Saving time is done right when you don't count the number of things to do but sum the time these things require to be done ;-)

Comment: @puck that's what they say in the 2nd-to-last paragraph. The whole point of this answer is that mgmt may be very happy with cheap buggy software (or actually working software with simply ugly code) that kind of does what they want, and that's what the employee is paid for.

Comment: @user you understood the problem ;-) Management is happy with botch because it's cheap. Not wanting to know that with some reworking future changes would be faster, that is not more expensive but more stable. Show me that one manager who, in case of problems, admits they wanted it to be that horribly bad. Then things turn quickly and nobody wants to hear that this style of work was enforced all the time.

Comment: @puck I think once you're in a situation, either owning a small business or managing a larger one, where you're controlling budgets and assigning dollar amounts to development resources... you'll very quickly understand why it is you don't want your $50/hr developer wasting an hour just compiling notes on why he thinks he should spend next year rebuilding an app he thought he could get done in a month, instead of doing what you asked him to do. Problem is exponentially worse, the smaller the user base of the app is compared to time spent / wasted

Answer (score 1):

How long have you been working there?  Not very long, I'm guessing.

Please consider how you will sound when you take it to your manager.  "Hey, boss, this stuff I'm working on is terrible.  You should really fix it up, and I'm just the person to do it.  It will only take a month!"  It is very easy to sound arrogant.

Remember that you are employed to either do work and solve problems that 1) make the organization money, or 2) save the organization money or time.  Everything you do must work towards that goal.  If you go to your boss and say "I don't like this thing that you have here, I need to fix it", you're not going to be seen in a positive light.

If you decide to push this issue, then yes you should, as noted above "Just stick to the facts, say what's wrong and what could be improved".  However, there must be a value to the work that you do, and you need to be able to quantify that value in dollars or hours.  No good boss will let you change something just because it's not how you like it.

Comment: Plus the "Code doesn't even have 10% comments" makes OP sound like they don't know what they are talking about. A lot of comments is not the same as maintainable code. In my experience a lot of comments can be an indicator to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

*(Chuckle ...)*  "Welcome to the industry."

If you haven't already done so, please check-out and read: *The Mythical Man-Month.*

"Of *course* you think that you can rewrite it." "Of *course* you are gung-ho to try."  But, what you really need to do right now is to gather up your thoughts and ***talk(!)*** to the responsible individuals – both other members of the team *(if any)* and the "stakeholders" by way of your manager.

*"What should I do if I find that the software is horribly designed?"*  Well, even though this isn't how software *starts,* yes, it is very often what it *becomes.*  And yet, you must find "a path forward."  Welcome to the business.  "Your *true* education" is about to begin.